# Migrate from ereg_replace to preg_replace

Tags: php

Just migrating from PHP 5.2 to 5.3, lot of hard work! Is the following ok, or would you do something differently?

```
$cleanstring = ereg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]^[,]^[.]^[_]^[:]", "", $critvalue);
```

to

```
$cleanstring = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]^[,]^[.]^[_]^[:]", "", $critvalue);
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a follow-up to cletus's answer:

I'm not familiar with the POSIX regex syntax (ereg_*) either, but based on your criteria the following should do what you want:

```
$cleanstring = preg_replace('#[^a-zA-Z0-9,._:]#', '', $critvalue);
```

This removes everything except a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the puncation characters.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not that familiar with the ereg_* functions but your preg version has a couple of problems:

1. ^ means beginning of string so with it in the middle it won't match anything; and
2. You need to delimit your regular expression;

An example:

```
$out = preg_replace('![^0-9a-zA-Z]+!', '', $in);
```

Note I'm using ! to delimit the regex but you could just as easily use /, ~ or whatever. The above removes everything except numbers and letters.

See [Pattern Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), specifically [Delimiters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Comment: Ah I see, so how would I match the ",._:" etc? This was written a while ago, I think I am trying to clean strings and keep everything a-z, A-Z, Number and ",._:" - everything else can be chucked away!

Comment: Regex characters need to be escaped (put a \ before them). This applies to |[]()-*+?{}^$\, the delimiter character and possibly others I'm forgetting.